# Sorcery undefined method `login_at'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I'm trying to get auth for Twitter and Facebook by this guide https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/External, but I've got a problem - `undefined method 'login_at' for #<OauthsController:0xa99d6bc>.` Frankly I can't find this function(login_at) in guide. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have External submodule included in your Sorcery configuration:

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:external, ...]
```